# React Component not setting HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm having a strange problem that I have not encountered before while using React.

I'm creating a Button component that needs to be backwards compatible with a legacy Button component. This is requiring me to do some unfortunate things in my implementation...

One of the issues with the legacy Button is that there is a typo for passing in a `tabIndex`. The legacy Button's property for `tabIndex` is `tapIndex`.

This should be easy to map using something like...

```
<Button tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex || this.props.tapIndex || 0}></Button>
```

But for some reason this is not the case...

If the `tabIndex` attribute of the child is mapped to `this.props.tapIndex` the rendered element will not have a `tabIndex` set. In short:

*This works*:

```
<Button
  ...
  tabIndex={this.props.tabIndex}
  ...
>Hello</Button>
```

*This does not*:

```
<Button
  ...
  tabIndex={this.props.tapIndex}
  ...
>Hello</Button>
```

I have debugged the execution of my component and `this.props.tapIndex` is indeed set correctly and equal to the intended value. But again, the `tabIndex` attribute does not exist on the rendered element in this case.

*Button.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  stylesToStyled,
  cleanClassNames,
  extractProps
} from '@ns/utils';

import getKind, {
  KINDS,
  KIND_DICT,
  PRESENTATION_DICT,
  BOOLEAN_PROPS
} from './utils';
import PrimaryButton from './components/PrimaryButton';
import SecondaryButton from './components/SecondaryButton';
import TertiaryButton from './components/TertiaryButton';


const TYPES = ['button', 'submit', 'reset'];
const COMPONENT_DICT = {
  [KIND_DICT.PRIMARY]: PrimaryButton,
  [KIND_DICT.SECONDARY]: SecondaryButton,
  [KIND_DICT.TERTIARY]: TertiaryButton,
};

class Button extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setAnalyticsMessageOnDOM();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setAnalyticsMessageOnDOM();
  }

  get StyledButton() {
    // Get the appropriate Component
    const kind = getKind(this.props, extractProps(
      this.props.className,
      BOOLEAN_PROPS
    ));

    // Add passed in styles
    const styles = stylesToStyled(this.props.style);
    return styled(COMPONENT_DICT[kind])(
      styles.properties,
      ...styles.values
    );
  }

  get tabIndex() {
    if (Number.isInteger(this.props.tabIndex)) {
      return this.props.tabIndex;
    }

    if (Number.isInteger(this.props.tapIndex)) {
      return this.props.tapIndex;
    }

    return 0;
  }

  setAnalyticsMessageOnDOM() {
    // Terrible Hack
    this.buttonRef.setAttribute(
      'analyticstrack',
      this.props.analyticstrackmessage
    );
  }

  render () {
    const {
      className,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    const { StyledButton } = this;

    return (
      <StyledButton
        className={cleanClassNames(className, BOOLEAN_PROPS)}
        tabIndex={this.tabIndex}
        innerRef={el => {this.buttonRef = el}}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
}

Button.propTypes = {
  [KIND_DICT.PRIMARY]: PropTypes.bool,
  [KIND_DICT.SECONDARY]: PropTypes.bool,
  [KIND_DICT.TERTIARY]: PropTypes.bool,
  [PRESENTATION_DICT.DISABLED]: PropTypes.bool,
  [PRESENTATION_DICT.INVERTED]: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  tabIndex: PropTypes.number,
  // Deprectation Warning: Typo that is being used in production, use tabindex.
  tapIndex: PropTypes.number,
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(TYPES),
  // Deprectation Warning: Use tabindex.
  kind: PropTypes.oneOf(KINDS),
  analyticstrackmessage: PropTypes.string,
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  [KIND_DICT.PRIMARY]: false,
  [KIND_DICT.SECONDARY]: false,
  [KIND_DICT.TERTIARY]: false,
  [PRESENTATION_DICT.DISABLED]: false,
  [PRESENTATION_DICT.INVERTED]: false,
  className: undefined,
  style: {},
  onClick: () => {},
  tabIndex: undefined,
  tapIndex: undefined,
  type: TYPES[0],
  kind: undefined,
  analyticstrackmessage: undefined,
};

export { TYPES };
export default Button;
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what may be causing this please feel free to comment or answer. Anything will be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue after trying @RIYAJ KHAN`s suggestion.

I changed from:

```
  render () {
    const {
      className,
      children,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    const { StyledButton } = this;

    return (
      <StyledButton
        className={cleanClassNames(className, BOOLEAN_PROPS)}
        tabIndex={this.tabIndex}
        innerRef={el => {this.buttonRef = el}}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
```

To:

```
  render () {
    const {
      className,
      children,
      tabIndex,
      tapIndex,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    const { StyledButton } = this;
    const tabIdx = { tabIndex: tapIndex || tabIndex || 0 };

    return (
      <StyledButton
        className={cleanClassNames(className, BOOLEAN_PROPS)}
        innerRef={el => {this.buttonRef = el}}
        {...tabIdx}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
}
```

Then slowly worked my way back to broken render method.

What I noticed is that in the latest example `tapIndex` and `tabIndex` are excluded in the `...props` rest expression which is added to `StyledButton` after my `tabIndex={...}`.

What I have determined is that when these properties are not excluded they somehow end up overwriting the `tabIndex` that I'm adding. So what is being passed to `React.createElement` is:

```
React.createElement(
  StyledButton,
  { ..., tabIndex: undefined, tapIndex: N },
  children
)
```

*Not* the `tabIndex` that I'm setting on the returned component.

My final solution is—render method only:

```
  render () {
    const {
      className,
      children,
      tabIndex,
      tapIndex,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    const { StyledButton } = this;

    return (
      <StyledButton
        className={cleanClassNames(className, BOOLEAN_PROPS)}
        tabIndex={tabIndex || tapIndex || 0}
        innerRef={el => {this.buttonRef = el}}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `object` for `tabIndex` and then assign it to `Button` using `spread operator`.

```
const tabIndex = {tabIndex:this.props.tabIndex || this.props.tapIndex }
```

Button

```
<Button {...tabIndex}
  ...

  ...
>Hello</Button>
```